# File creation not successful in if condition

Tags: shell

I am using a script which checks for command Timeout from plugged in device, and returns the date when the timeout is observed.

The script I wrote goes something like:

```
while true
do
     dmesg -c | tee -a dmesg_logs.txt
     grep "Timeout" dmesg_logs.txt
     if [ -z $?]
     then
        date | tee -a timeout_logs.txt
     fi
     sleep 20s
done
```

I am running the script by giving it execute permissions by issuing command:

```
chmod 777 timeout.sh
```

**The problem:**

When I run so, dmesg_logs.txt gets created and has all dmesg logs when script is run. But even when Timeout is observed in dmesg logs, timeout_logs.txt is not created.

Could anyone please help me understand this or maybe a solution as to how it is going to work?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `grep` and then `if [ -z $?]` (which is faulty) you can do:

```
while true
do
     dmesg -c | tee -a dmesg_logs.txt

     if grep -q "Timeout" dmesg_logs.txt
     then
        date | tee -a timeout_logs.txt
     fi
     sleep 20s
done
```

`grep -q` will return 1 or 0 depending upon whether `Timeout` is found or not in `dmesg_logs`.

Comment: Thanks anubhava...it works fine now....but I still do not understand as to why it did not work in d first place??

Comment: `if [ -z $?]` is bad syntax, it should be: `if [ $? -eq 0 ]`. `-z STRING` only checks if the length of STRING is zero.

Comment: If it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: i do not seem to have the reputation for the same. However it did work . Thanks "+1"

Comment: You can actually mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top left of my answer. This will give you bonus points also.